# Partition on Debian 10 with 2 Hard Drives (SSD/HDD)

Tags: debian-installer

Ok I'm trying to partition my system properly I want to install Debian, and I can't have it guide me automatically so I will Manually partition my disks. I have a 256 GB SSD(nvme) and a 500 GB HDD.
I've been digging everywhere to find clear instructions to this as I'm sure there have been many discussions that have been answered but there not clear enough for what I'm trying to accomplish so I hope to get some very good information here I can use forever.
I would probably assume a simple layout can be done all through the Debian installer, but maybe there is a better option?
So do I use Manual Partition.

Drive 1. SSD (nvme) will have / (the whole rest of space volume except for swap and boot) , swap=24GB (I have 12GB of ram) , and boot(efi)512MB

Drive 2. HDD will have /home and utilize it all, is this adequate?
This is what I assume to be the best course of action.

The boot efi partition has given me some trouble in the past I will not decide to partition my Physical Drives myself as I have in the past and have alot of remaining schemes on them. Is it ok to write over these or should I boot up a live installer and wipe the drives? I know my way around linux and servers but this whole Manual Partitioning has been giving me quite a headache, i want a solid install and not have to install and make changes after as that's been a bit of a pain in the past. Thanks alot guys, your advice is highly coveted and I appreciate it.

Warm Regards,

James

Comment: Manual partitioning works fine, I was reinstalling my machines without touching my existing data partition (even encrypted with LUKS) hundred times. IMO you should go like this: 1. split OS and user data, 2. have something which would allow you to "divide" storage on-fly. That is, either install LVM or go with *btrfs* on OS disk. For data disk use LVM for use. Benefits? Having separate OS and data disk you can be more secure while reinstalling. With LVM you can decide to use a LV as raw storage for a VM for better performance, or use multiple mount points with various mount options.

Comment: I often change partitioning with a new drive. But have Ubuntu on SSD & data on HDD. But newer NVMe drive gave me room for most of my data, so HDD now test installs & backup. If UEFI, be sure to use gpt on both drives. With gparted select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. Swap does not need to be larger than RAM. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu